# BASH script : list all files including subdirectories and sort them by date

Tags: bash, unix

I have a bash script:

```
for entry in "/home/pictures"/*
do
  echo "ls -larth $entry"
done
```

1. I want to list also the files in subfolders and include their path
2. I want to sort the results by date

It must be a bash script, because some other software (Jenkins) will call it .

Comment: requirement for bash because some other software will call it seems pretty ugly - other software could easily call python and you could use os.walk(). I don't have any nix at my hand, so if by evening not solved I can try to help with bash solution; but using google should solve your problem sooner

Answer (score 1):

Try find.

```
find /home/pictures  -type f  -exec ls -l --full-time  {} \; | sort -k 6
```

Comment: I tried all the 5 mentioned solutions, but all of them return :
find: bad option -printf so I guess it's the syntax mistake

Comment: Which system are you on ? Solaris doesn't have the -printf in find. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306752/solaris-find-doesnt-support-printf-action . You can try my answer which is without printf. What is the error here ?

Comment: I suspect `--full-time` is GNU specific. :/ http://www.shrubbery.net/solaris9ab/SUNWaman/hman1b/ls.1b.html

Answer (score 0):

**If there are no newlines in file names** use:

```
find /home/pictures -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n'|sort -n
```

If you can not tolerate timestamps in output, use:

```
find /home/pictures -type f -printf '%28T@ %p\n' | sort -n | cut -c30-
```

---

**If there is possibility of newlines in file name**, *and*, if you can make the program that consumes the output accept null terminated records, you can use:

```
find /home/pictures -type f -printf '%T@,%p\0' | sort -nz
```

For no timestamps in output, use:

```
find /home/pictures -type f -printf '%28T@ %p\0' | sort -nz | cut -zc30-
```

P.S.
I have assumed that you want to sort by last modification time.

Comment: I tried all the 5 mentioned solutions, but all of them return :
find: bad option -printf so I guess it's the syntax mistake

Comment: `find --version` output please? The commands work with `find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0-git` which i have. Try to find `-printf` in `man find` on that computer.

Comment: find --version says : find: illegal option -- version.    Info about my OS, Solaris:   

SunOS  5.10 Generic_Virtual sun4v sparc sun4v

So I guess these GNU tricks don't work, I also can't install anything.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution for my question:

find . -name * -exec ls -larth {} +